# Display grep output with line breaks inside a if statement in a bash script

Tags: bash, shell-script, grep, regular-expression

I want to validate a text file with a script.

The file to validate is:

```
FDFHDK JKL
1545665 152
HDKFHDK UHG
YRYRUBH DFG
867HDKE WER
```

Valid lines must match the regex `'[A-Z]{7}+[[:space:]]+[A-Z]{3}'`.

If all the lines are valid, the script shows a message saying that the file is OK.

If at there is at least one line that doesn't match the regex, the script should show a message and display the lines that don't match the regex.

The script is:

```
#!/usr/bin/env bash
result=""
output=$(grep -vE '[A-Z]{7}+[[:space:]]+[A-Z]{3}' "$1" |wc -l)
if [[ $output > 0 ]]
then
  echo "These lines don't match:"
  result="${resultado} $(grep -vE '[A-Z]{7}+[[:space:]]+[A-Z]{3}' "$1") \n"
  echo -e $result
else
  echo "The text file is valid"
fi
```

The expected output is

```
These lines don't match
FDFHDK JKL
1545665 152
867HDKE WER
```

But I'm getting

```
These lines don't match:
FDFHDK JKL 1545665 152 867HDKE WER
```

So the actual script is not taking the line break into account.

Comment: "So the actual script is not taking account the line break", see [Why does my shell script choke on whitespace or other special characters?](https://unix.stackexchange.com/q/131766/170373) and https://mywiki.wooledge.org/WordSplitting and quote any variable expansions like the one in `echo -e $result`

Comment: Thanks! Please also clarify if the regex was correct. Would `1234567abcdefg ABC` be valid, for example?

Comment: ` 1234567abcdefg  ABC` is not valid the regex is ` '[A-Z]{7}+[[:space:]]+[A-Z]{3} '`

Comment: Sorry, I meant `ABCDEFGABCDEFG ABC`. Would that be valid?

Comment: No, It would not be valid

Answer (score 5, accepted):

There is absolutely no reason to use an intermediate variable to store output of commands just to perform a test or output that data.

```
#!/bin/sh -

if grep -q -v -x -E -e '[A-Z]{7}[[:space:]]+[A-Z]{3}' -- "$1"
then
    echo 'Does not verify. Bad lines follow...'
    grep -v -x -E -e '[A-Z]{7}[[:space:]]+[A-Z]{3}' -- "$1"
fi
```

The regular expression has been corrected to delete the extra `+` after `{7}`.  The `if` statement tests the exit status of `grep` directly.  The `grep` command in the `if` statement, and later, use `-x` to force a whole-line match, and the first `grep` statement uses `-q` to stop at the first match without outputting anything.

The actual issue in your code is using `$result` unquoted, which causes the shell to split the value on spaces, tabs, and newlines, and then do filename globing on the generated words.  The final set of words are then given as arguments to `echo` which prints them with spaces as delimiters.

---

If you are concerned about running `grep` twice, then run it only once and store the output of it to e.g. a temporary file:

```bsh
#!/bin/sh -

tmpfile=$(mktemp)

if grep -v -x -E -e '[A-Z]{7}[[:space:]]+[A-Z]{3}' -- "$1" >"$tmpfile"
then
    echo 'Does not verify. Bad lines follow...'
    cat -- "$tmpfile"
fi

rm -f -- "$tmpfile"
```

Answer (score 4):

I propose this alternative:

```bsh
match="$(grep -vEx '[A-Z]{7}[[:space:]]+[A-Z]{3}' "$1")"
[[ "${#match}" -ne 0 ]] && printf "%b\n" "Bad lines:\n${match[@]}"
```

```
Bad lines:
FDFHDK JKL
1545665 152
867HDKE WER
```

---

Note [from @they's answer](https://unix.stackexchange.com/a/676788/338177):

> The regular expression has been corrected to delete the extra `+` after `{7}`